# ¿Como acceder y editar las propiedades de los controles que contiene un UserControl? C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Realizé un userControl que contiene una grilla Devexpress (DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl). Lo que quiero hacer es acceder a las propiedades de esa grilla en un formulario Windows Forms.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Saludos

Comment: Podrias explicar con codigo cual es la idea?    ´<br/> Los usercontrol existen en las aplicaciones y sitios web. Las aplicaciones window forms son aplicaciones de escritorio. No se pueden unir estos dos tipos de aplicaciones y modificar propiedades

Comment: @ctm002 el concepto de control de usuario existe tanto en aplicaciones Web Forms(https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol_members(v=vs.90).aspx) como Windows Forms (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol_members(v=vs.90).aspx) o WPF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol_members(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Sin ver código alguno, la forma mas fácil de poder acceder al Grid es declararlo como public.

Comment: claro, la propiedad modifier del control cambiala de private a public y con esto pudes acceder al control.

Comment: El user control se comporta como cualquier otra clase, si has definido metodos y propiedades publicas podras usarlas sino no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder a las propiedades de los controles del control de usuario deberías exponer estos valores a través de propiedades del control de usuario.

Por ejemplo, imagina que defines un control de usuario (`MiUserControl`) con un botón (`botonEnUserControl`) dentro de él.
Podrías hacer que desde fuera del control de usuario se pudiera leer y modificar el texto del botón a través de una propiedad `TextoDelBoton`.
O que se pudiera consultar el ancho del botón a través de una propiedad `AnchoDelBoton`.

```
public partial class MiUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MiUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextoDelBoton
    {
        get
        {
            return botonEnUserControl.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            botonEnUserControl.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public int AnchoDelBoton => botonEnUserControl.Width;

}
```

De esta forma si añades una instancia de tu control de usuario a un formulario (por ejemplo `MiUserControl1`) podrías acceder a estos valores a través de

```
 MiUserControl1.TextoDelBoton
```

o

```
 MiUserControl1.AnchoDelBoton
```

Answer (score 2):

No la hay de forma directa, se supone que la finalidad de un User Control es abstraer la funcionalidad que implementa, es por eso que no permite el acceso a las propiedades de los controles que contiene

Si necesitas configurar el Grid vas a tener que exponer una por una esas propiedades que necesites

```
public class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
   //resto codigo

   public GridColumn Columns 
   {
      get { return XtraGrid1.Columns; }
      set { XtraGrid1.Columns = value; }
   }

}
```

lo mismo aplicas a todas las propiedades de los controles internos que quieras exponer hacie fuera.

Si el user control contiene solo el grid quizas debas evaluar crear un Custom Control