# ¿Cómo comunicar 2 controles de usuario (UserControl) en C#?

Tags: c#, eventos, usercontrol

Tengo dos controles de usuarios y un formulario que contiene agregado a ambos controles, los cuales deben compartir información entre sí.

**Aquí explico:**

Del control de `Usuario 1 obtengo 2 datos`, los cuales van a ser recibidos en el **formulario**, y luego el formulario lo enviará al **control de usuario 2** para realizar una operación y luego ese `control de usuario 2 devuelva 1 valor al formulario`.

Con el valor que obtengo del `UserControl2`, lo usaré en el **formulario** para realizar un proceso.

En el **control de Usuario 1** tengo esto:

```
private string valor_devuelto1, valor_devuelto2= string.Empty;

public delegate void actualizar_ucontrol(string valor1, string valor2); 
public event actualizar_ucontrol actualizado;

public void ejecutar_evento()
{
   var evento = actualizado;

   if (evento != null) 
   {
      //Estas variables toma su valor cuando sucede algo en el Control de Usuario1
        evento(valor_devuelto1, valor_devuelto2); 
    }
}
```

En el **control de Usuario 2** tengo esto:

```
public string valor1, valor2 = string.Empty;

private string valor_devuelto= string.Empty;

public delegate void actualizar_ucontrol(string resultado); 
public event actualizar_ucontrol actualizado;

public void ejecutar_evento()
{
   var evento = actualizado;

   if (evento != null) 
   {
      //Esta variable toma su valor cuando se ejecuta la operación.
        evento(valor_devuelto); 
    }
}

public void realizarOperacion()
{
   //Realiza la operación y la variable "valor_devuelto" toma su valor.
   //......
}
```

> La función `ejecutar_evento()` en ambos casos solo se encargará de ser invocada desde el formulario a través del evento para devolver los  datos al formulario.

**En el Formulario:**

En un botón tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void boton_actualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Se suscribe al evento del control 1, invoca el evento y devolverá el dato al formulario.
   user_control1.actualizado += new user_control1.actualizar_ucontrol(ControlUsuario1_a_ControlUsuario2);
   user_control1.ejecutar_evento();

        //Se suscribe al evento del control 2, invoca el evento y devolverá el dato al formulario.
   user_control2.actualizado += new user_control2.actualizar_ucontrol(recibir_dato);
   user_control2.ejecutar_evento();

   //otras cosas ....
}
```

> El botón se encargará de suscribirse a ambos eventos, buscar los dos datos en el control 1 y como ocurrirá el evento en ese control 1 (Enviará esos datos al Control 2 y lo mando a ejecutar la función que realizará la otra operación.)

```
private void ControlUsuario1_a_ControlUsuario2(string _valor1, string _valor2)
 {
     ControlUsuario2.valor1 = _valor1;
     ControlUsuario2.valor2 = _valor2;
     ControlUsuario2.realizarOperacion(); 
 }
```

> Y también ejecutará el evento del control de usuario 2 para devolver el resultado de la operación nuevamente al formulario y continuar trabajando con ese dato.

```
private void recibir_dato(string _resultado)
{
    resultado_recibido = _resultado;
    //Continuar con mas cosas....      
}
```

**Nota:** este método **me funciona correctamente**, **pero** debe haber una forma mas práctica de hacerlo que no sea tan extensa. (Espero que hayan podido entenderme)

**¿Cómo lo puedo realizar de otra manera más eficiente?**

Encontré [esta informacíon sobre exponer propiedades dentro de un User Control](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80685/como-acceder-y-editar-las-propiedades-de-los-controles-que-contiene-un-usercont) , pero no es igual a lo que necesito.

Comment: Si entiendo bien tu pregunta,lo que quieres es poder acceder desde un control de usuario a propiedades o eventos del otro? Si es así, una opción sería desde el formulario principal pasar la instancia del control 1 al control 2 una vez creados ambos. De esa manera,el control 2 podría acceder al 1.

Comment: @Pikoh, si debo acceder a sus propiedades, `pero los eventos no se disparan para las aplicaciones contenidas` a menos que sea a través de un disparador de un evento para que si necesito por ejemplo actualizar un método este se actualice y se refleje mientras la aplicación esta en modo de ejecución. **¿Puedes traducir tu comentario a código de como hacerlo?**

Comment: La cosa es un poco amplia y necesitaría algo mas de información. Pero básicamente: Creas en tu UserControl2 un propiedad que sea `UserControl1 uc1 {get;set;}`. El formulario principal crea el primer userControl: `user_control1 = new UserControl1();` y despues el segundo `user_control2 = new UserControl2();`. Asignas la instancia del uc1 a la propiedad del 2: `user_control2.uc1=user_control1;` y a partir de ese momento, desde el uc2 tienes acceso a los eventos y propiedades del 1 con `uc1.evento+=...`

Comment: @Pikoh comprendo, que información necesitas? te la proporcionaré para que puedas darme una respuestas mas aceptada, te parece?

Comment: Por ejemplo, que es `evento` y `actualizado`. De todas maneras tendría que hacer un ejemplo para probarlo. Cuando tenga tiempo prometo darte un ejemplo.

Comment: @Pikoh `var evento = actualizado;` evento es una variable que tomará el valor del **event**  actualizado que pertenece al delegado **actualizar_ucontrol** , esta bien por favor cuando tengas tiempo para proporcionarme un ejemplo, aquí lo esperaré.

Comment: @Pikoh me ha olvidado, por favor cuando disponga de tiempo si puede hacer el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor, como comentaba @Pikoh, es poner un ejemplo de dos controles de usuario comunicándose de la forma que establecíais en los comentarios: que desde un control de usuario se haga referencia al otro a través de una propiedad.

Voy a plantear un ejemplo con dos controles tipo chat. Uno constará de un `TextBox` y un `Button` para introducir y enviar mensajes al chat, y el otro tendrá un único control `RichTextBox` en el que se mostrarán los mensajes ya introducidos.

Para el primer control crearemos un control de usuario `ChatInputCtl` en el que añadiremos un control `TextBox` (`tbInput`) y un botón (`btInput`).

El código del control de usuario quedaría:

```
public partial class ChatInputCtl : UserControl
{
    public ChatInputCtl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbInput.Dock= DockStyle.Left;
        btInput.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    }

    public new event EventHandler TextChanged
    {
        add { tbInput.TextChanged += value; }
        remove { tbInput.TextChanged -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler Send
    {
        add { btInput.Click += value; }
        remove { btInput.Click -= value; }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return tbInput.Text; }
        set { tbInput.Text = value; }
    }

    private void ChatInputCtl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Height = tbInput.Height;
        Width = Math.Min(Width, btInput.Width + 110);
        tbInput.Width = Width - btInput.Width - 10;
    }
}
```

En el constructor del control se establece que el `TextBox` se ajuste a la izquierda y que el `Button` se ajuste a la derecha. En el evento `Resize` recalculamos el tamaño de los controles para que el `TextBox` se ajuste al tamaño del control de usuario.

Lo importante es el resto del código. Creamos dos eventos `TextChanged` y `Send` que se lanzarán respectivamente cuando se genere el evento `TextChanged` del `TextBox` (se está escribiendo un nuevo mensaje) y cuando se genere el evento `Click` del `Button` (se envía el nuevo mensaje al chat).

Además se expone una propiedad pública `Text` que permite obtener o modificar la propiedad `Text` del `TextBox`.

Para el control que muestra los mensajes del chat crearemos un nuevo control de usuario `ChatDisplayCtl` con un único control `RichTextBox` (`rtbChat`). El código del control de usuario sería:

```
public partial class ChatDisplayCtl : UserControl
{
    private ChatInputCtl _inputControl;
    private string _fixedText = "";
    private string _currentText = "";

    public ChatDisplayCtl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rtbChat.Dock= DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    public ChatInputCtl InputControl
    {
        set
        {
            _inputControl = value;
            if (_inputControl != null)
            {
                _inputControl.TextChanged += InputControlTextChanged;
                _inputControl.Send += InputControlTextSend;
            }
        }
    }

    private void InputControlTextSend(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_inputControl.Text))
        {
            _fixedText += $"Yo: {_currentText}\n";
            _inputControl.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void InputControlTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _currentText = _inputControl.Text;
        RefreshText();
    }

    private void RefreshText()
    {
        rtbChat.Text = _fixedText;
        rtbChat.SelectAll();
        rtbChat.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentText))
        {
            rtbChat.AppendText($"Yo: {_currentText}");
            rtbChat.Select(_fixedText.Length, rtbChat.TextLength - _fixedText.Length);
            rtbChat.SelectionColor = Color.DarkRed;
        }
        rtbChat.SelectionStart = 0;
    }
}
```

El control de usuario tiene una propiedad pública `InputControl` que permite establecer el control de entrada de mensajes que utilizará. De esta forma, cuando se establece el valor de esta propiedad, podemos asociarle controladores a los eventos `TextChanged` y `Send` para que este segundo control reaccione a los eventos generados en el primero. Cuando se genera el evento `TextChanged` se actualiza una variable interna `_currentText` con el texto actual del control `InputControl`, mientras que cuando se genera el evento `Send` el valor de `_currentText` (el mensaje actualmente escribiéndose) se añade al contenido de la variable `_fixedText` (los mensajes ya enviados). El método `RefreshText` simplemente actualiza el contenido del control `RichTextBox` con el contenido de estas dos variables.

Para probar estos controles simplemente tendríamos que crear un formulario, añadir los dos controles y establecer el control `ChatInputCtl` como valor de la propiedad `InputControl` del control `ChatDisplayCtl`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chatDisplayCtl1.InputControl = chatInputCtl1;
    }
}
```

Y con esto ya deberían funcionar enlazados.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Entendí perfectamente, prácticamente solo me faltaba entender como exponer las propiedades del control, ya me ha quedado claro, Gracias.