# Duda: Columna DataGridView que solo acepte formato hora (12h/24h) en C#?

Tags: c#, formato, datagrid

Tengo un **DataGridView** que contiene varias columnas y hay **dos Columnas** que solo deben permitir que el usuario digitar la **hora**, lo he realizado de la siguiente forma:

Evento **EditingControlShowing** para invocar el método `KeyPress` :

```
    private void data_grid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textbox = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null)
        {
           textbox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(data_grid_KeyPress);
           textbox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(data_grid_KeyPress);
        }
    }
```

Método **KeyPress** :

```
private void data_grid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (data_grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 || data_grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        //(char)58 pulsan :
        //(char)65 pulsan A
        //(char)77 pulsan M
        //(char)80 pulsan P
        //(char)97 pulsan a
        //(char)109 pulsan m
        //(char)112 pulsan p
        //(char)46 pulsan .
        //(char)8 pulsan Borrar
        //(char)13 pulsan enter
        //(char)32 pulsan espacio

        //Nota: evento.Handled es false por defecto.

        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) | e.KeyChar == (char)8 | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape) // Si es un numero o borrar
        {
            e.Handled = false; // No hacemos nada y dejamos que el sistema controle la pulsación de tecla
            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)46 | e.KeyChar == (char)58) // Si es un punto o dos puntos
        {
            e.Handled = false; // No hacemos nada y dejamos que el sistema controle la pulsación de tecla
            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)65 | e.KeyChar == (char)77 |
            e.KeyChar == (char)80 | e.KeyChar == (char)97 |
            e.KeyChar == (char)109 | e.KeyChar == (char)112 |
            e.KeyChar == (char)32)
        {
            e.Handled = false; // No hacemos nada y dejamos que el sistema controle la pulsación de tecla
            return;
        }

        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Si es un enter
        {
            e.Handled = true; //Interceptamos la pulsación para que no la permita.
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}"); //Pulsamos la tecla Tabulador por código
        }
        else //Para el resto de las teclas
        {
            e.Handled = true; // Interceptamos la pulsación para que no tenga lugar
            data_grid.CurrentCell.ErrorText = "Solo se acepta formato de Hora.\n Ejemplo:\n     1:00 \n     2:00 a. m.\n     5:00 P. M.\n     15:00";

        }
    }
}
```

> Creé un método **KeyPress** para controlar las teclas pulsadas por el usuario y solo aceptar las que yo he definido en el método. Ambas columnas en la Propiedad : **DefaultCellStyle - Format** las tengo con el formato `hh:mm:ss tt` para que luego que el usuario termine de escribir la hora, me la coloque en ese formato especificado.

**¿Puedo realizar este tipo de columna sin necesidad de interceptar cada letra pulsada por el usuario?**

**EDIT:**

[Como en este ejemplo](http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com/2015/04/datagridview-columna-solo-numeros.html) de [@AsierVillanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva), creando una columna personalizada la cual pueda reutilizar cuantas veces la necesite.

**Nota:** NO debo usar un "DateTimePicker" , el usuario debe colocarla de forma manual, porque además cargará datos de la BD.

Comment: Puedes utilizar [este código](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormDataGridView-29783221/sourcecode?fileId=21769&pathId=412954589) para crear un MaskedTextBoxColumn que solo acepte entradas en formato 00:00 y posteriormente validar que la entrada sea correcta en algun evento de la celda tipo `CellValidating` por ejemplo.

Comment: @Pikoh, ok verificaré, Revisa en la parte final de mi pregunta agregue un `Ejemplo de una columna personalizada`, Quiero algo así.

Comment: @Pikoh el código que me mostraste en el enlace es bastante extenso, Wao! , el de `Asier` lo entiendo mejor, como puedo mencionarlo o citarlo para ver si puede ayudarme?

Comment: El código es extenso pero simplemente debes copiarlo en una clase en tu proyecto y usarlo exactamente igual que en el ejemplo de Asier, por así decirlo la clase que te he puesto sustituiría a `IntegerGridColumn` en su ejemplo

Comment: @Pikoh, lo que sucede es que no debo copiar por copiar, osea mas que copiar debo entender el funcionamiento porque de esa manera también aprendo. Y esto pertenece a un desarrollo en la empresa donde trabajo, no puedo implementar una clase con tantos componentes sin justificar su uso, no se si comprendes lo que quiero decir.

Comment: @Pikoh, fue un excelente aporte, si no puedo hacerlo de otra manera pues implementará este método, Gracias. `De paso: puedes responderme a la pregunta que te hice` [aqui, sobre los UserControls](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126169/c%C3%B3mo-comunicar-2-controles-de-usuario-usercontrol-en-c)

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar un DateTimePicker? ¿Porque el tipo de dato de la celda debe ser `string`?

Comment: @AsierVillanueva si, una porque debe ser string y otra porque es la manera que me exigieron en mi ambiente de trabajo. Con  `DateTimePicker` hubiese sido mas sencillo.

Comment: Si el problema es que el tipo de datos debe ser `string` no hay más que hacer la conversión al pasar el valor entre el editor y la celda. Es que no le veo ninguna ventaja a encapsular un `MaskedTextBox`, teniendo que hacer validaciones adicionales, en lugar de utilizar un `DateTimePicker` únicamente con la parte de hora, que ya te valida que el dato introducido sea una hora válida.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva puede proporcionarme un ejemplo utilizando el `DateTimePicker` en la grilla?

Comment: Uno para fechas tienes en mi blog: http://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/datagridview-columna-fechas.html

Voy a ver si puedo modificarlo para editar únicamente horas.

Comment: Correcto, de esta manera podría elegir el tipo de columna personalizada mediante el diseñador, y que yo pueda especificarle un Custom Format a: `hh:mm:ss tt` , si le es posible. estaré a la espera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque necesites que el valor de la celda sea de tipo `string` puedes editar el valor utilizando un `DateTimePicker`, simplemente deberás realizar la conversión de cadena a fecha y viceversa cuando se pase el valor entre el control de edición y la celda.

En primer lugar deberías crear el control de edición que tendrá que implementar la interfaz `IDataGridViewEditingControl` y que podría quedar como:

```
class TimeEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    private string _timeFormat = "hh:mm:ss tt";

    public TimeEditingControl()
    {
        Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        CustomFormat = _timeFormat;
        ShowUpDown = true;
    }

    // Value nullable
    public new DateTime? Value
    {
        get { return base.Value == MinDate ? (DateTime?) null : base.Value; }
        set
        {
            base.Value = (DateTime) (value == null ? MinDate : value);
            CustomFormat = value == null ? " " : _timeFormat;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            Value = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CustomFormat == " ")
            {
                CustomFormat = _timeFormat;
                Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        SendToGridValueChanged();
    }

    private void SendToGridValueChanged()
    {
        EditingControlValueChanged = true;
        EditingControlDataGridView?.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    }

    #region Miembros de IDataGridViewEditingControl

    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }

    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }

    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get { return Value == null ? string.Empty : Value.Value.ToString(CustomFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture); }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) value) ? (DateTime?) null : DateTime.ParseExact((string)value, CustomFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
            }
            catch { Value = DateTime.Now; }
            SendToGridValueChanged();
        }
    }

    public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set; }

    public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }

    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor => Cursor;

    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll) { }

    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange => false;

    #endregion

}
```

Como puedes ver el control hereda de `DateTimePicker` e implementa la interfaz `IDataGridViewEditingControl` para poder utilizarlo como editor de celdas en un `DataGridView`.

En el constructor se establece el formato de hora deseado y se establece la propiedad `ShowUpDown` a `true` para que muestre los "spin buttons" en lugar de el calendario.

Lo más importante del código del control está en la propiedad `EditingControlFormattedValue`. En los métodos `get` y `set` de esta propiedad es donde se convierte el valor de cadena recibido de la celda a un valor fecha para asignar al `DateTimePicker` y viceversa.

Ten cuidado con el formato de hora que has elegido porque el control `DateTimePicker` hay veces que no muestra correctamente los sufijos AM y PM dependiendo de la configuración regional del usuario.

Para poder mantener valores nulos o vacíos he sobrescrito la propiedad `Value` del `DateTimePicker` para que admita estos valores. Cuando se establece un valor nulo el valor del control base se establece a `MinDate`. Para que en estos casos la fecha no se visualice la propiedad `CustomFormat` se establece a un espacio de forma que el control aparece vacío.

La tecla "Suprimir" permite establecer el valor vacío o nulo, mientras que cualquier otra tecla restablece el formato para poder introducir una nueva hora.

A continuación deberíamos crear la clase para la celda que heredará de `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` y que simplemente tendrá código para indicar que el editor de la celda debe ser una instancia de `TimeEditingControl` y para establecer el valor del editor a través de la propiedad `EditingControlFormattedValue`:

```
public class TimeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public override Type EditType => typeof(TimeEditingControl);

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        var editingControl = (TimeEditingControl)DataGridView.EditingControl;
        editingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue = Value;
    }

}
```

De la misma forma crearemos la clase `TimeColumn` para la columna, en la que simplemente indicaremos que se debe utilizar la clase `TimeCell` para generar las celdas:

```
public class TimeGridColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{

    public TimeGridColumn() : base(new TimeCell()) { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
                    !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TimeCell)))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Debe especificar una instancia de TimeCell");
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

A partir de aquí se podría crear por ejemplo una propiedad en la columna para especificar el formato de hora o aprovechar la propiedad `Format` de `DefaultCellStyle`.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71214/discussion-on-answer-by-asier-villanueva-duda-columna-datagridview-que-solo-ace).