# ¿Cómo pasar datos entre controles de usuarios de distintos forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Hola  como puedo hacer para pasar datos que se encuentran en un UserControl del form2 para pasarlo a un UserControl del form1?? utilizo Windows Forms - C#.

La idea es que estando en el Form1 ante un doble click se muestra el form2 para seleccionar información, luego esta información se tiene que pasar al UserControl del form2 para ser guardado en la BD. Un ejemplo seria seleccionar el cliente de un form emergente (form2) y que se cargue en el encabezado del pedido (form1)

estuve tratando de hacerlo con eventos y delegados pero no me doy cuenta como plantearlo

Comment: Sería bueno que [edit] tu pregunta e incluyas [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para saber con exactitud lo que quieras. La forma como lo planteas puede darse como muy amplia.

Comment: Recientemente aquí en SO hice [una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126169/c%C3%B3mo-comunicar-2-controles-de-usuario-usercontrol-en-c?noredirect=1#comment235491_126169) que te funcionaria para hacer lo que deseas. Hechale un vistazo. Fue respondida por el usuario [@AsierVillanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva), con [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/128328/69447) podrás realizar lo que planteas en tu pregunta. Exponiendo las propiedades que deseas pasar de un control a otro y usando los eventos y delegados. _Puedes obtener una

Comment: @Davlio ahora adjunto el código que tengo actualmente, tengo dudas respecto a si es una solución optima o si se puede mejorar

Answer (score 1):

Veamos si esto es lo que querías. Dos formularios Padre e Hijo. Un botón en el Padre crea el Hijo y un botón en el Hijo pasa datos al Padre.

En el formulario padre creamos un delegado (al que llamamos Delegado), con la firma del método al que referenciará, el paso de un parámetro de tipo cadena.

Al crear el formulario hijo el evento Click del botón, y antes de mostrar el formulario, procedemos a registrar el método de envío de datos en el delegado del formulario hijo.

Y terminamos creando un método para la recepción de datos del hijo.

```cs
public partial class frmPadre : Form
{
    public frmPadre()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //crear el formulario hijo
        frmHijo frm = new frmHijo();

        //registrar método de recepción parámetros formulario padre 
        frm.envioParametros += new Delegado(recepcionParametros);

        //muestra el formulario en modo modal
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    //metodo para la recepción de parámetros
    private void recepcionParametros(string param)
    {
        textBox1.Text = param;
    }
}
```

El formulario hijo declaramos un objeto del tipo Delegado.

En el evento Click del botón se enviarán los datos que contenga al formulario hijo.

```cs
public partial class frmHijo : Form
{
    //declarar la función de delegado
    public Delegado envioParametros;

    public frmHijo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //envío de la notificación a la ventana padre
        envioParametros(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```